# Need to add checkbox along with sosl search results

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

I am new to salesforce development and my requirement is perform dynamic search using sosl query. Display product details along with checkbox for product selection. I displayed the search results in visualforce page but unable to add checkbox.

Apex code:

```
    prodlist = New List<Product2>();
    searchquery = string.escapeSingleQuotes(keyword);
    system.debug('&&&&&&'+searchquery);        
    if(searchquery != null){
    List<List<SObject>>searchList = Search.query('FIND \''+searchquery+ '\' IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING Product2(Name,IsActive,Brand__c,Vendor_Style__c, where IsActive=true)');
    system.debug('&&&&&&'+searchList);
    prodlist = ((List<Product2>)searchList[0]);
```

Visualforce code:

```
         <apex:pageBlock id="pageblockId3" title="Product Details" rendered="{!prdselect}" >
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!prodlist}" var="prod">       
                 <apex:column value="{!prod.Name}" headerValue="Product Name" />                   
                 <apex:column value="{!prod.Vendor_Style__c}" headerValue="Vendor Style" />                
                 <apex:column value="{!prod.Brand__c}" headerValue="Brand Style" />
                 <apex:column value="{!prod.IsActive}" headerValue="Active" />
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
              <apex:pageBlockButtons >
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: You can achieve this using wrapper class.

Comment: Hello Abhishek, 
Can you please provide me any sample code for this scenario.

Comment: Please refer this link https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. Now I am able to display results with checkbox.

Comment: Appreciate your efforts!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is just for illustration purpose.

create a simple wrapper class with a Boolean attribute and product sObject type variable with default as false on the constructor for boolean

```
 public class wrapProduct {
            public Product Prod {get; set;}
            public Boolean selected {get; set;}

            public wrapProduct(Product pr) {
                Prod = pr;
                selected = false;
            }
        }
```

In the class where you are querying product list add the below code and construct the wrapper list

```
public List<wrapProduct> wrapProductList {get; set;}
```

instead of exposing list of products in UI expose the list of wrapper class instance

```
 for(Product pr: lstProducts) {// list of products output from your SOSL
                // As each Account is processed we create a new wrapAccount object and add it to the wrapAccountList
                wrapProductList.add(new wrapProduct(pr));
            }
        }
```

Once users have selected the products use the same controller variable to update the product flag which are set to true on the wrapper class variable selected

Comment: Thank you. Now I am able to display results with checkbox.